# simulator blackberry 9550 not launching

Tags: eclipse, blackberry

Anyone know.. what is this? "jvm error 104 uncaught classcastexception" this message shown in my simulator simulator blackberry 9550? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that an Exception is occurring when you are trying to cast an object with a class.. I had a similar issue and that was the problem I found.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown a single line of code, but I'll hazard a guess: you're trying to cast an object to a type which it does not subclass.

Comment: @Jamaley: not unless you provide a code snippet that demonstrates the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask